# PHP If / ElseIf statement not working

Tags: php

I wrote below code in PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['vote']) ){
    if ($_POST['vote'] == 'a') {
        //code1
    } elseif ($_POST['vote'] == 'b') {
        //code2
    }
}
```

When

`$_POST['vote'] = 'a' //code1 is run`

but when

`$_POST['vote'] = 'b'//code2 is not run.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add your form to the question

Comment: It seems you are not closing your main `if` you're losing you `}`

Comment: @Jeff that would result in a compile error, looks like an incomplete snippet

Comment: @rndus2r thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: we don't know what is there  in `//code1` and `//code2` so do like :-`if (isset($_POST['vote'])) {
    if ($_POST['vote'] == 'a') {
        echo "code1";
    } elseif ($_POST['vote'] == 'b') {
        echo "code2";
    }
}` and check second part is working or not  when `$_POST['vote']= b`

Comment: print_r($_POST) to see what data it has.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works fine.

But, alternatively, you can try:

```
switch($_POST['vote']){
    case 'a':
        //code a
        break;
    case 'b':
        //code b
        break;
}
```